# How to configure log4j.properties file to print parent class of the class from where the logging has been made?

Tags: java, logging, configuration

I tried to check various docs, but everything is telling about the current class, not parent.

Suppose I have below code. How do I log something like: 
2019-09-03 | INFO | A.a -> B.b | I am B

```
class A {
 void a() {
   B.b();
  }
}
class B {
 void b() {
  log.info("I am B");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a logger using Log4J or SLF4J, you first declare like this.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Current class Name")
or
Logger logger = Logger.getLoggerFactory("Current class Name");
```

It means you declare log, it will print in the same class not in the inherited class.
If you want to print in the parent class, you have declare it in the parent class method.
The main objective here is to track where the problem is.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. I am talking from log4j configuration perspective rather than coding perspective. We have different pattern options like, %L, %C, etc., which we configure either in properties file or in xml file to show line number, caller class, etc.. I wanted to know, if such type of option exist to print the name of parent class/method, here, for e.g. A/a.

Comment: I don't think this kind of configuration is available.